# Background image not saved

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my windows phone 7  application, i used a default application background. An i also used     Photo Chooser Task to the users to keep their own custom skins. It works perfectly but when the user exits the app and if relaunches the app again, still the app has the default background. But I need the app to remember the last background that is set by the user and should not get changed until the user change the background. I researched so many places but i can't find the suitable answer for this. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance for your hard work!

Comment: You could save the image in the Isolated Storage : http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---Read-and-Save-Images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you want to use IsolatedStorageSettings.  It's basically storage that your app can access easily. Just find a way to store the info you need to determine the background.

Here is my favorite howto on the subject: http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/15/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-15-isolated-storage/

Edit:  Sorry, I put the wrong link in!  It leads to some great sample code.

Comment: Can you put your codes here because am new to these things??? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I fixed the link in my answer.  It leads to some really good sample code now.

Comment: That was a good sample Jeremy. But in that app it's retrieving the text only after we click on the button(Retrieve File). But on my app, when the user launches the app, the retrieving file should be default and not by clicking it.

Comment: Look in your App.xaml/App.xaml.cs(or.vb) file.  There will be an event for the app being loaded (not at my normal computer, otherwise I could give you the exact name).  You can put the code to retrieve the background image in there.

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting! Do you have any samples or any site for this?

Comment: Go into your app.xaml.cs file.  Find the "Application_Activated" function.  Put the code for handling the background loading in there.

Comment: I forgot to tell this, your sample can be used for text but i need for images.

Comment: IsolatedStorageSettings is a Dictionary<string, object>.  You can put what you need in there, just remember to cast it.